# Magento 2 override module-ui from custom theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, requirejs

Is there any option to override magento-ui  `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates` templates from a theme?

**Other module's templates overriding works fine:**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/estimation.html': 'template/module-checkout/estimation.html',
            'Magento_Checkout/template/progress-bar.html': 'template/module-checkout/progress-bar.html'
        }
    }
};
```

But I see that module-ui templates' path is declared this way:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
    }
}
```

And I can't override this file:

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/textarea.html

Comment: Have you did it?

Comment: But not work for me. What you write in 'requirejs-config.js'?

Comment: Where you want to override? In a module or in a theme?

Comment: In a module....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try to create in your theme a `Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element/textarea.html` file ? This should override the base one , also don't forget to remove the theme files from `pub/static/`, this worked for me

Or in your custom module , create a `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` file in your module with the following code

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/estimation.html': '[Namespace]_[Module]/template/module-checkout/estimation.html',
            'Magento_Checkout/template/progress-bar.html': '[Namespace]_[Module]/template/module-checkout/progress-bar.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Creating the exact path works, but the requirejs-config.js does not with Magento_Ui... I tried everything possible... If someone knows how to do it...

Comment: @PolRavalitera What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @VladPetru I want to rewrite form/field.html from the requirejs-config.js , in order to put my new field.html in a module. I cleaned cache, everything, that just do not work on 2.1.7. The exact path in theme worsk (Magento_Ui etc).

Comment: @PolRavalitera I just tried to override that exact file, it is working but be carefull, the requirejs-config file doesn't always update after one refresh, if the cache is done for some files it leaves them like they are. You should clear magento2 cache and browser cache, if its not working manualy delete the file from pub/static/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/[lang_code]/Magento_Ui/templates/form/

Comment: @VlaPatru I just add a lot of problem on that, i had to delete static/frontend/_requirejs . I don't know why, but the "secure" version of it is not updated... So i thought maybe that was just that last time with this problem. I will retry. Thx you for looking into it !!!

Comment: try : 
   bin/magento setup:upgrade 
instead of :
   bin/mangento cache:clean
(setup:upgrade will force magento to discover the new templates)

Answer (score 2):

Create `requirejs-config.js` file from `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/base`.

So path will be `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/base/requirejs-config.js`

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                'Magento_Checkout/template/estimation.html': '[Namespace]_[Module]/template/module-checkout/estimation.html',
                'Magento_Checkout/template/progress-bar.html': '[Namespace]_[Module]/template/module-checkout/progress-bar.html'
            }
        }
    };
```

and run the commands

`php bin/magento cache:flush`
`php bin/magento cache:clean`

then you can check `[root]/[pub]/[static]/[_requirejs]/[frontend]/[Namespace]/[theme]/[en_US]/requirejs-config.js` your code will update here.

So it will work. feel free to ask if you have any queries?

Comment: How can I override file-uploader.js from module-ui under web/js/form/element ? I did try as you suggested but not working.