# override base template file in adminhtml [Magento-Ui backend]

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, overrides, grid

I created custom grid module using ui component layout

In that i want to add new button near to filter button.

That new button should functions like action drop down function i.e capture all selected items in grid.

For adding new button i followed link

[Magento 2 override module-ui from custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149515/magento-2-override-module-ui-from-custom-theme)

I think the above link for front end theme development. But i want back end module

I tried to override following file in my admin module as follows in link above but its fails.

**Magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\templates\grid\filters\filters.html**

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create the following module to override **filters.html** :

1 Module Name: SG_AdminJS

2 Create **registration.php** inside **SG/AdminJS/** with following code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SG_AdminJS',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

3 Create **module.xml** inside **SG/AdminJS/etc/** directory with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SG_AdminJS" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Ui" />
            <module name="Magento_Backend" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

4 Create **requirejs-config.js** inside **SG/AdminJS/view/base/** with following code:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'ui/template/grid/filters/filters': 
              'SG_AdminJS/template/grid/filters/filters'
        }
  }
};
```

5. Now copy **filters.html** from **vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/filters/filters.html** and paste this file into following directory inside your module:

   > SG/AdminJS/view/base/web/template/grid/filters

Now activate the module and flush the cache by executing the following commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Note: I have tested this module in 2.3.0 and it's working fine.

Hope it will help someone.